# How do I prevent overflow in CSS?

Tags: css, html, xhtml

I have this code in CSS:

```
#top_bar {
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
border: 3px solid gray;
/*margin: 0px;*/
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

And I run into the problem of having it overflow and I can't see the end of my status bar(because it's off of the page). It doesn't show a scroll bar(I don't want it to) but I want it to exactly hit the end the of the page, not go over it.
It is going over on the right side.

Answer (score 3):

Take the padding off, the width is being set as 100% + 10px at the moment. You could then add the padding to a container within `#top_bar` eg.

```
#top_bar .inner {
  padding:10px;
}

<div id="top_bar">
  <div class="inner">
    ...Content...
  </div>
</div>
```

Or alternatively you can change the `box-sizing` to force the box model to ignore the padding when calculating the width:

```
#top_bar{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Or use padding: 10px 0;, or use line-height instead of padding.